# How to show Row() children size fitted to screen?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

How to fix the error in different screen sizes
i want the middle text should be fitted if the screen have space
if the screen dont have space it should TextOverflow.ellipsis

this is my code

```
      Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
              child: Icon(
                MdiIcons.alertCircle,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 16,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Text(
                "Your Service Request Has Been Approved",
                maxLines: 1,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 13,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
              ),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
              child: Icon(
                MdiIcons.close,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 16,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: Wrap the inner container with Expanded and remove the height you are giving. An expanded widget will make the container take up the complete space that is available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Expanded`  widget

```
Expanded(
 child: Text(
            "Your Service Request Has Been Approved",
            maxLines: 1,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 13,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
          ),
        )
)
```

Comment: You can wrap container widget inside expanded and remove for text widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `Spacer` widget and wrap `Container` with `Expanded` widget like code below:

```
Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: Text(
                "Your Service Request Has Been Approved",
                maxLines: 1,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 13,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

As you asked in one of the answer's comment, to show full text when wrapped with `Expanded`, All you have to do is wrapped it with `FittedBox`. This will allow to resize font size according to available width.

```
 Expanded(
             child: FittedBox(
              child: Text(
                "Your Service Request Has Been Approved",
                maxLines: 1,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 13,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
              ),),
            ),
```